# Dereferencing a Two Dimensional Array In C

Tags: c, arrays, dimensional

I'm having some difficulties understanding two dimensional arrays in C.
Let's look at this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int arr[2][3]) {
    printf("%d", *arr); 
}

int main() {
    int arr[2][3] = {   {10, 20, 30}, 
                        {40, 50, 60}
                    };
    foo(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. What is the value of **arr**? Is it the address of arr[0][0]?
2. If **arr** is the address of arr[0][0], then why the line: 
    *printf("%d", *arr);*
   doesn't print the value 10?
3. Each time I run it, I get a strange number. what is the meaning of this number?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can't print an array using `%d`.  If you loop over `arr`'s elements, this should work.

Comment: (2) Because the address of the array is the address for the first element. Your rows are `0, 1`, your cols are `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: Every question is *wrong*. 1. value of `arr` **where**? 2. This isn't even wrong, 3. undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your questions:

1. Used in an expression, the value of `arr` is a pointer to its first element.  Since it's an array of arrays, the pointer to its first element is `&arr[0]`.  This value has an unusual type, "pointer to array of 3 ints".
2. Because `arr` is not the address of `arr[0][0]`.
3. This is a crazy situation, hard to understand and hard to explain.  In brief: since `arr` is a pointer to an array, `*arr` is that array.  But when you try to pass it to `printf`, the compiler turns around and generates a pointer to the array's first element again.  I suspect that pointer value differs because your compiler and OS are putting `main` (and therefore `arr`) in a different place on the stack each time.  (And then there's the additional problem that since we're talking about pointers, it doesn't necessarily work to print them `%d`, especially if your machine has 32-bit ints and 64-bit pointers.)

My advice to you is not to worry about why the incorrect code printed changing values.  Rather, please just print the array correctly, with code like this:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: 1. Let's say arr[0][0] is at address 1000. What is **&arr[0]**? What address is it?

Comment: @MikeT The simple answer is 1000.  But it's a misleading question.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by doing like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int arr[2][2] = {{2,3},{5,6}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        for (int j = 0;j < 2; j++) {

            printf("%d\n" , *(&arr[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```